# How to remove a task that runs before Windows boots

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, tasks

I recently ran a program that is supposed to check the disk for errors. It wanted me to restart the computer so it can check the disk before Windows boots. I did, but there was some problem with it (probably related to the fact that the program was run off of a portable drive) and now whenever I restart/boot the computer, it throws the error and I have to press a key to continue.

Any ideas of how to remove this tasks? It seems that it would remove the task itself if it would have ran correctly, but since it did not run correctly, it did not remove itself and is now always running at boot. I would think that I could simply remove it manually, but I cannot find any way to remove it.

I am uncertain if the task starts before Windows boots, or after Windows starts but before Windows' user interface starts (if this is even possible).

All ideas would be wonderful!

### Edit

Here is some additional information:

- OS: Windows 10 (previously Windows 7)
- Manufactorer: HP
- Program used: Disk Check (made by IObit), which is included in IObit Toolbox (both of which are now obsolete). Both "" and Toolbox are portable applications.
- Error message:

  > Invalid system disk
  >
  > Replace the disk, and then press any key

The strange thing is, this happens when the portable drive is connected and disconnected. When it is connected, it has the same drive letter in Windows as when I used it and got into this whole mess.

Comment: Please provide the name of the program and the exact error message, this will help us to help you

Comment: @TomEus I added the program name and error message, along with other information. Please let me know if anymore is needed.

Comment: Removing the ability to boot from uefi devices and having the hard drive boot first seems to fix it. I will see if it is still fixed if I reenable the uefi booting. Either way, I would still like to know what could be happening and a better way to fix the issue. Edit: just reordering the boot order to have the hard drive boot first fixes it. Also uefi devices seem to take precedence over the original "legacy devices".